# ¿Cómo evitar este dato duplicado en consulta eloquent de laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mi controlador:

```
$results= posts::join('cities', 'posts.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
                ->join('provinces','cities.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
                ->groupBy('province', 'city')
                ->selectRaw('count(provinces.province) as total_province, provinces.province as province, cities.city as city, count(cities.city) as total_city')
                ->get();
return view('web/post', compact('posts'));
```

Recibo en la vista con blade dentro de un foreach:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div>{{ $post->province }}</div>
    <div>{{ $post->city }} ({{ $post->total_city }})</div>
@endforeach
```

Lo que necesito es que me muestre la ciudad y la cantidad de posts que hay en ellas, y funciona bien... El problema es que quiero agruparlas para mostrarlas en la vista por provincias y me muestra el nombre de la provincia por cada ciudad que encuentra, me devuelve lo siguiente en la vista:

Provincia: Buenos Aires Ciudad: Miramar (4) Provincia: Buenos Aires Ciudad: San Isidro (2) Provincia: Chubut Ciudad: Playa Unión (1) Provincia: Córdoba Ciudad: Almafuerte (1) Provincia: Córdoba Ciudad: Quilino (1) Provincia: Entre Ríos Ciudad: Hasenkamp (1) Provincia: La Rioja Ciudad: Vinchina (1)

El problema está acá:

Provincia: Buenos Aires Ciudad: Miramar (4) Provincia: Buenos Aires Ciudad: San Isidro (2)

Quisiera que solo me muestre una vez Buenos Aires (El nombre de la provincia). Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Utilicé GROUP_CONCAT pero me repite la provincia por el número de registros encontrados y quedan separados igualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera:

```
@php $currentProvince = '' @endphp
@foreach($accommodations as $accommodation)
    @if($accommodation->province != $currentProvince)
        <div>{{ $accommodation->province }}</div>
        @php $currentProvince = $accommodation->province @endphp
    @endif
    <div>{{ $accommodation->city }} ({{ $accommodation->total_city }})</div>
@endforeach
```

Me acuerdo de la última provincia que he pintado y si es la misma, no hago nada.
Cuando tengo una provincia distinta pinto.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó muy bien.